# Excel SumProduct if Columns Empty

Tags: excel

I am trying to calculate a `SUMPRODUCT` of 3 columns

[image]

My formula for a Cell is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((E5:E14)-(I5:I14))*F5:F14)
```

I need to remove the columns in "I" that have cell values of Empty or Null, The present formula is considering 0 for nulls. How do I accomplish with the formula

Comment: What is your desired result? In the formula above, it looks like 0 values will essentially be ignored since it will be subtracting by 0 (although this won't be the case if you use multiple arrays in the `SUMPRODUCT`, where it will multiply by 0).

Comment: I need to ignore the rows that have the "I" Column values in  null or empty.

Comment: Using the formula above, I get 62 ((5-1)*1 + (2-0)*21). Is that not what you wanted? Also, since you're using `SUMPRODUCT`, you can take out the `*` and replace it with a comma (to indicate two different arrays).

Comment: No I need to exclude the 2nd row altogether and have (5-1)* 5 = 20, I can be having other rows , if cell in column I is null or empty I need to remove the row from the calculation. I should NOT treat Null or empty as 0

Comment: Oh my bad, that totally makes sense. I'll post an answer - see if that helps at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can try is using the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(I5:I14<>""),E5:E14-I5:I14,F5:F14)
```

This checks if cells in column `I` are empty, and if so, it returns 0; otherwise, it returns 1. Your calculation is then run, but anytime an empty `I` is encountered, your product gets multiplied by 0 and is effectively removed from the sum. Here we separate the arrays by commas - these are what gets multiplied when calculating the product. The `--` forces the results of the `I5:I14<>""` evaluation to return a 1 or a 0, which is then multiplied through the rest of the values.

Comment: @Greens Added it to the answer - it ensures that you have values of 1 and 0 so that the multiplication works as expected (`TRUE` = 1, `FALSE` = 0).

Comment: Thanks you very much. Learnt something new

Comment: @Greens No problem at all, good luck with everything - you were definitely close with your formula.